# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar un objeto de una lista?

Tags: kotlin

Tengo una lista mutable de objetos de una clase simple;  Y además, tengo un objeto de esa misma clase. Debo mostrar la lista, pero antes debo asegurarme que ninguno de los objetos coincide con el objeto que e me pasó.

Tengo algo así (simplificado para la pregunta):

```
class MiClase {
  var codigo: String? = null
  var texto: String? = null
}

class OtraClase {

  var misObjetos: MutableList<MiClase> = ArrayList()

  //.....
  fun miFuncion(objeto: MiClase) {

    // eliminar los objetos de la lista que coinciden con el objeto pasado
    misObjetos.forEach {
      if (it.codigo.equals(objeto.codigo)) {
        misObjetos.remove(it)
      }
    }
  }

}
```

El código compila pero al ejecutarlo, si se encuentra un duplicado, se muestra un error en tiempo de ejecución:

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null

¿Por qué recibo ese error? ¿Y cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Es como en java, debes obtener un iterador de la lista y recorrer el iterador con el foreach, solo así puedes hacer remove. De la forma que lo pones no se puede porque al hacer el remove modificas el size de la lista.

Comment: Hola, intentaste con `removeIf` ?

Comment: ¿Cómo se haría eso?

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal pon eso como respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cito y traduzco la respuesta de [leonardkraemer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50032174/5213794), donde obtuve la información.

> En Kotlin, se puede usar `removeIf{ predicate }` , que es una forma
>   abreviada de usar `Iterator`